# First Generation/Sibling Match? (using one to one DNA comparison)

Tags: dna, gedmatch.com

Trying to wrap my head around this to determine if this is a legitimate sibling match (?)using report I got on GedMatch (one to one comparison DNA).
Report shows: 3557.3 total Autosomal cm/largest 206.6 total x DNA 196.1/same for largest. Report says 1st generation. I am very new to understanding any of the DNA reports with all the terminology/science. If not a sibling match what would the match indicate or is there a better report to use?